# assigning two variables to one list slice

Tags: python, list, pattern-matching, slice

Is it possible to assign to a list slice in one go, that would achieve the following as:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

xs = mylist[:-1]
x  = mylist[-1]

xs == [1,2,3,4,5,6]
x  == 7
```

I know I can write it like this:

```
xs,x = mylist[:-1], mylist[-1]
```

but I was wondering if it is possible to this any other way. Or have been spoilt by Haskell's pattern matching.

something like `x,xs = mylist[:funky:slice:method:]`

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name in Python. You will trash the `list()` constructor built-in!

Comment: You should edit your question for the great unwashed who may read it.

Comment: @ThemanontheClaphamomnibus http://sscce.org/#co

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can in Python 3:

```
>>> *xs, x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> xs
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> x
7
```

Comment: Of course. for some reason I had only been using this on tuples.

Comment: Damn, I wish I could switch to Python 3 already. This syntax is so nice.